# Auto log in SSH using expect

Tags: bash, expect

I wrote a script to auto login into a remote server. The login data is stored in a database.

```
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no $SSHUser@$SSHHost
match_max 100000
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "$SSHPass\r"
send -- "\r"
expect eof
EOD
```

This works, it logs in succesfully, but I can't interact. No keypresses are sent to the server.

Comment: Why not use public-key based authentication and a [local authentication agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent). It's much more secure and equally convenient.

Answer (score 2):

#### Why Your Script Closes the Socket

Whenever an expect script reaches the end of the file, it closes all spawned processes and exits. In other words, it's currently behaving as-designed.

#### Keeping the Socket Open for Interaction

What's missing is using the *interact* command when you see a command prompt. For example, after sending your password:

```
expect {\$\s*} { interact }
```

In your particular use case, you could simply call *interact* immediately after sending your password without waiting for the prompt, but the example above is generally a better practice that allows you to handle other sorts of situations if you choose to do so.

Interact will allow you to do what you want: to interact with the SSH session. This will continue until you close the connection, and the spawned process exits.

#### See Also

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236894/is-it-possible-to-automate-ssh-login-with-passwd-not-passphraseless-ssh/12237702#12237702

Comment: I actually did try that, adding `expect {\$\s*} { interact }` but it does not work.

Comment: @skerit That's probably because stdin is already used by your here-document. Try putting the commands in a script instead of a here-document, e.g. `expect -f '# your commands here'`.